# Regexp to and from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to store and retrieve regular expressions from sessionStorage. Unfortunately the string representation of a RegExp is not a valid RegExp pattern.

Basically, I need the following snippet to return true.

```js
var originalExpression = /SomeRegularExpression/;
var newExpression = new RegExp( originalExpression.toString() );

document.write("Are equals: " + (originalExpression.toString() == newExpression.toString()));
```

I do not know beforehand how the regular expression will be. All I know is that I have a variable with a regular expression (actually a array or RegExps) and I need to store it, and then, retrieve it.

Is there some magic property or recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.source` property of regex to store it:

```
var newExpression = new RegExp( originalExpression.source );

console.log("Are equals: " + (originalExpression.toString() == newExpression.toString()));
Are equals: true
```

Or to preserve flags use:

```
var newExpression = new RegExp( originalExpression.source, 
         originalExpression.toString().replace(/.*\//, '') );
```

Comment: Do you lose the flags though? `/a/g.toString() == new RegExp(/a/g.source).toString()` gives me false.

Comment: @jon was first, but your code have a example that keeps the flags!.

Answer (score 2):

You would just save the `RegExp.source` property to SessionStorage:

```
var originalExpression = /SomeRegularExpression/;
var newExpression = new RegExp( originalExpression.source );
```

You can also preserve the flags by querying various properties (e.g. `global`, `ignoreCase`).

Comment: Also, note ES6 has a [`.flags`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.flags) property.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to string since this syntax is now allowed:

```
var myRegexObject = new RegExp(/mypattern/im);
```

So, this should work:

```
var originalExpression = /SomeRegularExpression/;
var newExpression = new RegExp( originalExpression );
console.log("Are equals: " + (originalExpression.toString() == newExpression.toString()));
```

Comment: I need to store the Regular Expression in SessionStorage, so I NEED to convert it to string. (the snippet is just a simplification of the actual code)

Comment: @Fernando: I mean "you don't need to convert it to string" to build an other RegExp object. If you want to convert it to string to store it, it isn't a problem.